# The package tabularray doesn't seem to work on Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, tabularray

I don't know if it's only me and is it the right place to report but this code compiles fine on a local LaTeX distribution (TeXLive 2021) whereas Overleaf generates errors. It seems it's the case only with the `tabularray` package. I was wondering if there are settings I missed.

The code

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{booktabs}{colspec = ll}
    \toprule
    Here...             & ... it works. \\
    \midrule
    Here...             & ... it works. \\
    And...              & ... {here\\it does too!} \\
    {But\\here...} & ... it does not. \\
    Some more text.     & Even more text. \\
    \bottomrule
\end{booktabs}
\end{document}
```

and errors:

I've got the following errors:

```
LaTeX Error: Environment booktabs undefined.
[Multiple] Misplaced alignment tab character &.
...

Undefined control sequence.
...
```

EDIT.
Versions on Overleaf:

- TeXLive: 2021 3 MAR 2022 12:42
- `tabularray`: 2021-07-01

Comment: You might want to list which version of `tabularray` you are using and which texlive you are using in overleaf. Overleaf is not always using the latest package versions, especially not if you are compiling using older TexLive i overleaf.

Comment: look in the log at the tabulararray package version, not the version of texlive. your loca texlive 2021 probably had updates up to the current time,  but overleaf's texlive 2021 is a frozen one from last summer.

Comment: I've checked the versions. Thanks for the clue. TeXLive on Overleaf is up to date but `tabularray` is a couple of months behind.

Comment: Overleaf never do `tlmgr update` once they provide a texlive version so any packages added during the year will not appear (apart from critical updates) until they roll out texlive 2022

Comment: `\begin{booktabs}` should be `\begin{tblr}`. Same for `\end`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Overleaf, TeXLive 2021 includes version 2021L (2021-07-01) of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package, which is a little old.

You can download the latest version from CTAN and upload it to your Overleaf project:

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray

Note that `tabularray.sty` is version `2022A`, and `tabularray-2021.sty` is version `2021Q`.

Answer (score 4):

A solution that works for me ... simply upgrade the version of TeX Live

(On Overleaf)

Menu **->** TeX Live Version **->** 2022

Comment: Now Overleaf has already installed TeXlive 2022.